# Get list of publications from Content Delivery

Tags: content-delivery, web8.5, cil

I'm trying to get a list of all *published* publications from Content Delivery.

I've tried so far using:

```
PublicationCriteria pubCriteria = new PublicationCriteria(0);
Query q = new Query(pubCriteria);
string[] pubIds = q.ExecuteQuery();
```

And also tried

```
ItemTypeCriteria pubCriteria = new ItemTypeCriteria(1);
Query q = new Query(pubCriteria);
string[] pubIds = q.ExecuteQuery();
```

Both cases return 0 results. Am I missing something obvious here?

To be clear, I don't really care about the publications themselves, but rather for the pages in them, and wanted to do some queries "per publication".

Something like this would return *all pages* but that would be around 100,000 in total and I wanted to break down my script to do one publication at a time.

```
ItemTypeCriteria pageCriteria = new ItemTypeCriteria(16);
Query q = new Query(pageCriteria );
string[] pageIds = q.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: Does `new PublicationMetaFactory().GetAllMeta()` do what you want?

Comment: This does work Albert! Put it up as an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `new PublicationMetaFactory().GetAllMeta()` to retrieve a list of all published publications.